# City wise shipping without zipcode

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I want to add shipping city wise and without zipcode.
I think to add dropdown for cities is important here.
I checked out this [link](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-city-as-dropdown-option-in-checkout-billing-shipping-address/)

But couldn't understand what i will have to do in order to add shipping city wise.

Comment: City drop-down is not necessary.  You need to customize the magento `shipping table rates` to accept city as a configuration parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free Matrixrates extension supports changing shipping prices based on city (as well as all the standard tablerates fields).

It won't add a dropdown though, I think thats covered in your link, its relatively easy to do.

https://marketplace.magento.com/shipperhq-auctionmaid-matrxrate.html